# Why are they called "first integrals"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If I have a differential equation, $\dot{x}(t)=f(t,x(t))$, then the functions $F$ that verifies $F(t,x(t))=const$ are called first integral? Where does this name come from?
Also, I read [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/First_integral) that :

> The knowledge of a first integral "reduces" the number of unknowns by
> 1

What does this mean exactly. If I have a system with just one variable $\dot{x}(t)=f(t,x(t))$, and I have a first integral $F$,then what does it mean to reduce the number of unknowns by 1? I know that $F(t,x(t))=const$, but I still don't have an explicit expression for $x(t)$, no?
If I have two variables $x=(x_1,x_2)$, and again I know one first integral $F$, why (what does it mean) to reduce de degree by one?

Answer (score 18):

"When the given differential equation is of order $n$, and by a process of integration an equation of order $n-1$ involving an arbitrary constant is obtained, the latter is known as the **first integral** of the given equation."

**Example:** Consider a given differential equation $y''(x)=f(y)$ where $f(y)$ is independent of $x$.

This equation become integrable if you multiply $2 y'$ in both side of the equation.Then we get 
$2 y' y'' = 2 y' f(y) $

and after integrating we have $(y')^{2} = 2 \int{f(y) dy} + c$ , where c is constant of integration.

this latter equation is called the *first integral* of the given differential equation.

(See "*Ordinary Differential Equation*s" by  *E. L. Ince* )

In your case, your *first integral* is your solution. Actually for first order differential equation integral and solution are equivalent.

Let's come to the answer of your second query now.

"The strength sounding name *first integral* is a relic of the times when the mathematicians tried to solve all differential equations by integration. In those days the name *integral* (or a *partial integral*) was given to what we now called a *solution*." (See "*Ordinary Differential Equations*" by *Vladimir I. Arnol'd*)

If you integrate the given differential equation for the first time you got the *first integral* . If you again integrate the *first integral* you got an equation called the *second integral* and so on. Ultimately by this you will get your desire solution of the differential equation.

Now the third one.

*First integral* reduces the order of the differential equation by one and there fore the number of unknown by one.

In particular take the previous example. Let us take $f(y)= y^{2}$ , then the differential equation becomes $y''(x)= y^{2}$. It's first integral is $(y')^{2} = \frac {2}{3} y^{3} dy + c$.

Suppose you are given the first integral as $(y')^{2} = \frac {2}{3} y^{3} dy + 3$ , then after solving this first integral you get only one unknown which you got from the last integration.

I thought by the word 'The knowledge of a first integral "reduces" the number of unknowns by 1' they mean this.

Comment: Sorry for replying to this old post, but how did you obtain $(y')^{2} = 2 \int{f(y) dy} + c$? With respect to which variable did you integrate $2 y' y'' = 2 y' f(y)$? Seems like $y$, but since the function "$y$" doesn't depend on the variable "$y$" I don't get how you've obtained this ... But I guess I'm something anyway, since I suppose there is a reason why you've labeled both a function and a variable with the symbol $y$.

Comment: What do you want to mean by "the function $"y"$ doesn't depend on the variable $"y"$" ? By the way the integration is with respect to $x$.