# relationship between ODE and the 1st integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There’s an ODE. Is there a theory on the relationship between the original ODE and the 1st integral of this ODE? Are they exactly equivalent or is one a subset of the other?

For example, to solve
$$
u’’+u=0, \qquad u(t=0)=u_0, \qquad u’(t=0)=u’_0 
$$
where $‘$ denotes time derivative. The 1st integral of this ODE is $$
u^2+u’^2=u_0^2+{u’_0}^2
$$
with $u(t=0)=u_0$. Seemingly, the ODE has 2 initial conditions (ICs) while the 1st integral has only 1 IC. The 1st integral seems to be equivalent to $u’=\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$ or $-\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$ with $u(t=0)=u_0$, which yields a monotonic solution of $u(t)$ rather than periodic. The monotonic solution is a subset of the periodic solution. Why here obtained a monotonic solution of $u(t)$ while the original 2nd order ODE yields a periodic solution? Will the answer to this specific question answer the general question in the last paragraph?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense and seems to be a little confused. I don't know what you mean by 'are they exactly equivalent or is one a subset of the other', there are no sets here of any kind and there is nothing to equate. The relationship between an ODE and its first integral is just that the first integral is a conserved quantity that is derived from an ODE (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203855/why-are-they-called-first-integrals) for more), or the ODE can be considered as the derivative of the first integral.

Comment: thanks I modified the question which now contains a general and specific question. These two questions are related

Comment: The problem lies in the statement 'which yields a monotonic solution of $u(t)$'. This is not true, which can be seen by directly integrating the problem.

Comment: The integral of the equation $u''+u=0$ is $u' + \int udt = 0$, not $u^2+(u')^2 = u_0^2+(u'_0)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that you want to use the trigonometric identity $\cos^2x+\sin^2x$, because you already know the answers and thus expect $u=\sin,\cos$, in order to substitute and solve $u'=\pm\sqrt{1-u^2}$. However, the $\pm$ sign coming from the said trig identity is ambiguous, because it depends on $x$; indeed, one has for example $\sin(x) = \mathrm{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$, that is why the sign of $u'$ is not constant and $u$ is not monotone.

Comment: thanks if my method was wrong, what is the correct way of solving? $u^2+(u')^2 = u_0^2+(u'_0)^2$ with $u(t=0)=u_0$

Comment: @feynman Don't worry, your method is correct, but you just cannot conclude that $u$ is monotone from $u'=\pm\sqrt{1-u^2}$, because, after separating the variables, you will integrate $\int\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ and the non-constant sign is actually hidden in the Jacobian of the substitution $u=\sin,\cos$, that is why this sign problem is dealt automatically without paying attention at first glance.

Comment: I think the 2nd order ODE is equivalent to repeatedly solving the 1st integral as in this sequence $u’=\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$, $u’=-\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$, $u’=\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$,...? Each element of this sequence contributes a monotone solution of u(t)?

Comment: @feynman Yes. In other words, you can see the solution as piecewise monotone. However, that's nothing special, since all (smooth) functions are locally monotone.

Comment: but $u’=-\sqrt{(1-u^2)}$ with $u_0=1$ yields u=1 for all t, i.e. u simply can't move away from u=1. This difficulty doesn't appear in the 2nd order ODE. How to explain this inconsistency?

Comment: @feynman Because $f(u, t) = \sqrt{1 - u^{2}}$ is not [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Theorem) in $u$.

Comment: @MatthewCassell thx so much. Not being lipschitz continuous is almost non differentiability around u=1. What implication does that yield?